# Is it true that $A_{ij} B^i \mathbf{E}^j = A_{pq} B^q \mathbf{E}^p$? Can we move indexes in doing inner products?

Tags: inner-products, tensors, index-notation

(in the question indexed $\mathbf{E}$ are contravariant basis vectors of a given coordinate system)

The equation in the title of the question is a consequence of the solution of this exercise (I introduced $p$ and $q$ to not repeat the same symbol for different dummy index in the same equation, but the tensors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the same in both side of the equation)

[image]

I could ask the question like this: tensor calculus books are said to pay carefully attention to the index order; but when the inner product is made, the indexes can be moved back and forth? In the first solution $\mathbf{E}_k$ is pushed behind $\mathbf{E}_j$, is it permissible (in the second solution too $\mathbf{E}_k$ is pushed back but it is different, after marrying $\mathbf{E}_j$ whit inner product, the object loses all its free index and it became a scalar)? If this is the case, if it is doable, how could be true that, for higher rank tensor, inner product is not commutative? If both solution are correct and the equation I wrote in the title works, how can I see that the two vectors obtained are the same? I'm confused in understanding the permissible ways in doing inner product. If only I had a simple geometrical meaning like vectors inner products, probably all would be clear. As far as I see, a rank 2 tensor in a $n$-dimension space is a sort of linear combination of $n^2$ dyads (and each dyad is a ordered double vector: we make $n^2$ dyads coupling in all the way a vector basis of the space) like a vector is a linear combination of $n$ vector. Is this correct? If this is the case, in this perspective, is there a simple way to see geometrically what a tensor inner product is? If answering to all this is too long I'll understand things later, but please simply tell me if moving $\mathbf{E}_k$ as the book do is correct and so if works $A_{ij} B^i \mathbf{E}^j = A_{pq} B^q \mathbf{E}^p$.

### Edit

I expanded. $\mathbf{E}^i$ are linearly independent so the only way the equation works is that works
$$A_{11}B^1+A_{21}B^2+...+A_{n1}B^n=A_{11}B^1+A_{12}B^2+...+A_{1n}B^n$$
and other $n$ similar equations. Simmetry of $\mathbf{A}$ would ensure that, but in general this is not true. The book is Taha Sochi's one (solutions, pag 75).

Comment: What book is this? Expand them out and see what happens.

Comment: @topologicalmagician Well, evidently in tensor analysis notations are so ugly that equality is not transitive. Maybe it would be better that in case of ambiguity the notation for the inner product specifies whether which indexes are contracted. Near the dot or something like that. I find it ugly writing a=b and a=c if b and c are different.

Answer (score 1):

$$
A_{ij}B^i {\bf E}^j = A_{qp} B^q {\bf E}^p
$$
since one can just change the names of dummy indices. In general,
$A_{qp} \ne A_{pq}$ so the result is *not* equal to
$A_{pq} B^q {\bf E}^p$. However, if $A$ is a symmetric tensor then
$A_{qp} = A_{pq}$ and then the equation you asked about does hold.